# Getting error 3709 while executing a vb script

Tags: sql-server-2005, vbscript

So I have this code where I am trying to connect to a dsn in sql server 2005.

```
Dim cn, cmd

set cn = createobject("ADODB.connection")
set cmd = createobject("ADODB.command")
cn.open ("dsn=LBILLBKP;UID=lbmkbkp;PWD=lbmkbkp")
cmd.activeconnection = cn

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  ErrLog "Export Script backup Err# 1 " & Err.Description, ErrFile, fso
  MailMsg = "The " & Region & " ListBill Export process failed while taking Database backup. Check the server log files (Scrpt.log, Error.Log, ftp.log)"
  MailRtn = SendMail(MailList, MailMsg, "0", "0")  

If MailRtn <> "0" Then
  ErrLog "Export Script backup Err# 2 " & MailRtn, ErrFile, fso
End If

fso = Empty 
WScript.Quit
End If

set cmd = nothing
cn.close
set cn = nothing
```

But it is throwing 3709 error. I have checked the connectivity to the database with the ID mentioned and have also checked the dsn manually, which is supposed to take a database backup, and have successfully completed the backup. I have checked the dsn with the same ID from Data Source (ODBC), it is working fine. I have also added 
    wscript.echo("") 
after every statement in the code to check which statement is not executing, but it seems that the job is running fine and every step is executing.
Please suggest what I should do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your method doesn't work. 
Personally I use a different technique, which does work (at least for me). Maybe you can try this. You will have to adapt the script to your situation!
The advantage of not using DSN is that the script will always work (as long as the database server can be reached of course) and not only on computers where the dsn has been defined.

```
Dim strServer, strDB, strUser, strPwd, objMyConn, strSQL, objMyRecordset, x

'Declare variables
strServer = "mssql1\mssql1inst1"
strDB = "Obelix"
strUser = "myusername"
strPwd = "mypassword"
Set objMyConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objMyRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'Open Connection
objMyConn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & strServer & ";Database=" & strDB, strUser, strPwd

'Set SQL Command
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM addressformatheading"

'Open Recordset
objMyRecordset.Open strSQL, objMyConn

'Do something with the data
Do Until objMyRecordset.EOF
  For Each x In objMyRecordset.Fields
    Wscript.Echo x.name, " = ", x.value
  Next
  Wscript.Echo
  objMyRecordset.MoveNext
Loop

'Clean up
objMyRecordset.Close
objMyConn.Close
```